# MapReduce: Reduce halts indefinitely while writing to context

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

The following is a map reduce program, in which a filtering is done in the map function and a summation is done in the reduce step.

The map part executes fine. But when the reduce part runs, it gets stuck at the line **context.write(key,value)**.

This happens specifically only when i try to write a different output in reduce function type than what is written in map function

```
public class Filter3 {

public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Contestant>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String[] cols = value.toString().split(",");

            try {
                Contestant val = new Contestant(cols[0],cols[1],cols[2]);

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(key+" ::: ");
                System.out.println(val);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();

                val.name = val.name.toUpperCase();

                if(val.rating>=9) {
                    context.write(new Text(val.name), val); //write null if it is not required
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static class AvgRatingReducer extends Reducer<Text,Contestant,Text,DoubleWritable> {

        private DoubleWritable result = new DoubleWritable(0.0);

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Contestant> values, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {        

            double sum = 0.0;
            int count = 0;

            for (Contestant val : values) {
                sum += val.rating;
                count++;
            }

            if(count>0) {
                result.set(sum/(double)count);
            }

            System.out.println(result);

            context.write(key, result);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "AvgMRJob"); //configuration and job name

        job.setJarByClass(Filter3.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(AvgRatingReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(AvgRatingReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        Path inPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outPath = new Path(args[1]);
        outPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outPath,true);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

The writable object used is here:

```
public class Contestant implements Writable {

    long id;
    String name;
    double rating;

    public Contestant() {}

    public Contestant(long id, String name, double rating) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Contestant(String id, String name, String rating) {
        try {
            this.id = Long.parseLong(id.trim());
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
        this.name = name;
        try {
            this.rating = Double.parseDouble(rating.trim());
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput inp) throws IOException {

        id = inp.readLong();
        name = WritableUtils.readString(inp);
        rating = inp.readDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

        out.writeLong(id);
        WritableUtils.writeString(out, name);
        out.writeDouble(rating);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.id + "," + this.name + "," + this.rating;
    }
}
```

The execution gets stuck in reduce function when writing output to context. I get no error/exception. It just hangs indefinitely.
I could not figure what is the issue. I have followed the usual procedure of a MapReduce.

[image]

**NOTE:
The same program works if i write data of same type in both map and reduce. i.e. if i write(key=Text,val=Contestant) in both Map and Reduce function. - instead of using DoubleWritable in reduce!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the combiner:

```
// job.setCombinerClass(AvgRatingReducer.class);
```

If you use a combiner, you need to make sure that the reducer works on the output of the combiner class, not the mapper.

Comment: that was so silly of me... But, why it did not throw any error/exception? - i'm wondering!!!

Comment: The issue was not because of that reason. But, program will work if your edit is done.
The real issue is that the Combiners input key-val pair and output key-val pair must be same. Here, in my reducer, it is different and hence cannot use that as a combiner.
The real reason is that the combiner pre-requisites are not met correctly.

Comment: @vivek_nk that's exactly what my answer says.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But, an elaborate answer on the reason would be useful for others like me. :) Just adding that in addition to your answer. Thanks @Thomas

Comment: your edit is wrong. There is no such restriction that a combiner input KV and output KV must be of the same types. You need to match the types of the components: Mapper Output KV needs to match Combiner Input KV, Combiner Output KV needs to match Reducer Input KV.

Comment: I too thought the same.. but when i surfed about that, found this - http://blog.optimal.io/3-differences-between-a-mapreduce-combiner-and-reducer/
It wuld be great if you can give a link with an example where combiner has different input and output (key,val) pairs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212884/mapreduce-combiner - please refer this. Now all is clear. (But anyway, Thanks. your fix worked only for that scenario.)

Comment: @vivek_nk again, this tells that you need to match between Combiner and Reducer, not that combiner in and output needs to be of the same type.

Comment: Did you get a change to read Donald miners answer (the second one) which clearly says that.

Answer (score 0):

**The mapreduce Combiners input `<key,value>` pair and the output `<key,value>` pair must be same.** That is the rule for the combiner, whereas for reducer, this rule is not there.

In this case, the reducer is reading a `<key,value>` pair `<Text,Contestant>` which is same as that of mappers output, and writes a `<Text,DoubleWritable>` as output `<key,val>` pair.

So, without a combiner, this will work. On adding a combiner, we must ensure that the input `<key,val>` pair and output `<key,val>` pair is same for the combiner step.

ie `<key1, value1, key1,value1>`

Here, the **mistake was using the same reducer class as a combiner**, since the above said rule is not satisfied. The reducers input `<key,val>` pair is different from output `<key,val>` pair.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212884/mapreduce-combiner - After some research, got the actual reasoning for it.